# How to add a dependency file in AWS Lambda Console with CloudFormation Package

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

My AWS lambda function `MyLambda` requires a file called `auxiliary.json`. I manually created the function and the file in the console and it is working fine.

Now, I would like to do this using CloudFormation so that I can see both the lambda function code and the file content on the console, and it works the same way it does with the manually created one. I do not want to package it with as zip and push it to S3 bucket.

I have the files in my code folder in the following structure:

```
.
├── lambda-template.yaml
└── lambdas/
    ├── mylambda.py
    └── auxiliary.json
```

In `lambda-template.yaml`, I have the lambda resource like below:

```
Resources:
  MyLambda:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:      
      FunctionName: "MyLambda"
      Code: lambdas/mylambda.py
      Handler: "MyLambda.lambda_handler"
      Runtime: "python3.8"
      Timeout: 30
      MemorySize: 128
```

After running the `aws cloudformation package` like below, I get the code from `mylambda.py` added to `mylambda-template.packaged.yaml` file.

```
aws cloudformation package \
   --template-file mylambda-template.yaml \
   --s3-bucket example-bucket \
   --output-template-file mylambda-template.packaged.yaml \
   --profile myawsprofile \
   --region us-east-1
```

And, I can deploy the packaged template like below with no issue:

```
aws cloudformation deploy \
   --template-file mylambda-template.packaged.yaml \
   --stack-name mylambda \
   --profile myawsprofile \
   --region us-east-1
```

However, I cannot add the required file `auxiliary.json` in the console using CloudFormation. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Code` is the path to only mylambda.py

```
Code: lambdas/mylambda.py
```

You should make it to directory:

```
Code: lambdas
```

Comment: Uh, It worked like a magic! Thanks so much, @Marcin!